# If statement is always coming up true

Tags: c#

I'm trying to play with progress bars. I click and it will progress 1% and so on.
I wanted it to reset after reaching 100% but it doesn't and instead it keeps going to negative numbers.

`maxProgress = 100;`
`Clicks = 0;`
`CPC = 0.01f;`

```
    public void clicked()
{

    clicks += CPC;

    if (clicks == maxProgress);
    {
        clicks -= maxProgress;
        complete++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: If you're playing with floats and comparisons you'd be better off using less than or equal instead of equality checking

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: What type is CPC?

Comment: CPC is a float variable.

Comment: I agree with @Sayse, try `if (clicks >= maxProgress)` but also remove the `;` right after the if()

Comment: Note: still incomplete, we can't see the Types or Scopes of the variables involved. There is so much more that you could have done wrong. Think about the C in [mcve]

Comment: Oh man, thank you Henk. So boneheaded of me. the `;` of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public void clicked() {

 clicks += CPC;

 if (clicks >= maxProgress) {
  clicks -= maxProgress;
  complete++;
 }
}
```

Remove the `;` on the `if` statement.